# how to create multiple TABLES in a single DATABASE in SQFLITE FLUTTER

Tags: sql, database, flutter, sqflite

I have 2  classes that have 2 different tables and methods for them like insert delete

The first class is called `ContactsSqfLiteHelper`
Second class `AddTxnSqfLiteHelper`

The first class has a databaseName, `laneDane.db`, also this is the first file to be executed, that means the DB is created on the user phone with the table i want to be created, yes it works fine

but when the other class exectes - `AddTxnSqfLiteHelper`
i also have the same Database Name specified there but i have specified different table name with different columns,

but this Files gives an error while executing, that no table found with this table name

First file

[image]

Second file

[image]

Since the Database name is same, but it gives an error

ERROR

[image]

But if I change the Database name in the second file it works, but this means i have 2 databases on the user device I don't want that,
I want 1 database with 2 tables

onCreate Method
for `ContactsSqfLiteHelper`

```
Future<void> _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE $_tableName ($_columnId integer primary key autoincrement, $_columnUserId integer no null,$_columnName TEXT NOT NULL, $_columnProfilePic TEXT NULL, $_columnPhoneId TEXT NOT NULL)');
  }
```

for `AddTxnSqfLiteHelper`

```
Future<void> _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE $_tableName ($_columnId integer primary key autoincrement, $_columnUserId integer not null,$_columnCategoryId integer NULL, $_columnUserContactId TEXT NOT NULL, $_columnType TEXT NOT NULL, $_columnAmount DOUBLE NOT NULL)');
  }
```

INSERT FUNCTIONS
-> `AddTxnSqfLiteHelper`

```
static Future<int> insert(Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
    // will return the DB from the getter
    final db = await instance.database;
    return await db.insert(
      _tableName,
      data,
    );
  }
```

-> `ContactsSqfLiteHelper`

```
static Future<int> insert(Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
    // will return the DB from the getter
    final db = await instance.database;
    return await db.insert(
      _tableName,
      data,
    );
  }
```

How i am getting the DAtabase
For both the file same

```
Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database!;

    final dir = await sql.getDatabasesPath();
    final tablePath = path.join(dir, _dbName);
    // sql.deleteDatabase(tablePath);
    // print('DATABASE DELETED');
    _database = await sql.openDatabase(tablePath,
        version: _dbVersion, onCreate: _onCreate);

    return _database!;
  }
```

_dbName -> Database name

Comment: Please share oncreate function where you are creating table and database

Comment: Yes @Ahmad i have added it, check the edits

Comment: Print the _tableName in AddTxnSqfLiteHelper  _onCreate function and see what it returns

Comment: Also the problem is in your insert function can you please post that also

Comment: Ok would you take a time, to check again